# How to make an image appear only for 2 minutes using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a script in which an image appears for the user for only 2 minutes. Think of it as a timer. And once the timer reaches 5, an image should disappears. I am pretty new to javascript, so I really have no idea where to start. Does anyone know of a script which will do the job, or maybe point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `setTimeout` function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Make the image disappear
}, 2 * 60 * 1000); // 2 minutes
```

You can make the image disappear by getting a reference to the `img` element:

```
var img = /* ...get the image... */;
```

...for instance, using an `id`:

```
var img = document.getElementById("theImage");
```

...but there are several other ways, [on modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) you can use just about any CSS selector with `document.querySelector` (to find the first matching element) or `document.querySelectorAll` (to get a list of all matching elements).

Then either remove it from its parent:

```
img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
```

...or hide it:

```
img.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out:
HTML:

```
<img id="myimage" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"/>
```

javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'none';},20000);
```